# Debian stuck on terminal after turning my laptop on

Tags: linux, debian, boot, gui

I have a newly installed debian on my laptop and it's currently stuck:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 10 debian tty1
debian login: _
```

No GUI login form is shown even after waiting for a long period of time.
I can login with my account credentials, but it does not change anything. What should I do to display the GUI login form?

Comment: Did you install graphical packages, or console only?

Comment: Does `startx` work?

Comment: Welcome, run `tasksel` as root, then select and install a GUI.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk startx - command not found.

Comment: @GAD3R - I tried tasksel as root but nothing happens after I run this. Probably I will have to use some additional option. 
I tried sudo apt-get cinnamon but it was not recognized. 
I guess my mistake was that I installed os from pendrive with netinst image but without network access and now I do not have gui...

Answer (score 1):

Using a netinst iso without an Internet connection, `apt` will fail to configure your `sources.list` correctly.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follow:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main 
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main 
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
```

To install cinnamon desktop:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install task-cinnamon-desktop
```

Comment: I tried sudo apt but it also failed :( Ultimately I just downloaded full ~4gb image with all needed packages and installed debian again on my computer..